# ARC: Version & updates

Tags: google-chrome-arc

1. How can I get the version of the currently running App Runtime for Chrome on the Chromebook and programmatically?
2. Does ARC get updates and how often?

Comment: This may help: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Build.ID is the version number.
2. Major release is bound to Chrome's release cycle, so roughly every 6 weeks.